# JavaScript - Put decimal in String backwards

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to put in a decimal at a certain index of a String, like this:

addDec("2342355", 2)

should return:

"23423.55"

What's the fastest way to do this? No parsing to Number allowed.

Comment: What do you mean by "allowed"???

Comment: `'2342355'.replace(/(\d{0,2})$/, '.$1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addDec(number, shift) {
    return number.slice(0,number.length-shift) + '.' + number.slice(number.length-shift)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addDec(num,pos) {
    var newNum = num.substr(0,num.length-pos) + "." + num.substr(num.length-pos, num.length);
    return newNum;
}
```

Comment: `substr()` is more efficient if old IE is not a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to utilize a string splice function:

```
String.prototype.splice = function( idx, rem, s ) {
    return (this.slice(0,idx) + s + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem)));
};
```

Then in your code you can modify:

```
function addDec(number, index_for_decimal) {
    return number.splice(index_for_decimal, 0, '.');
}
```

Varied results based in index:

```
addDec('12345', 2);
=> "12.345"
addDec('12345', 4);
=> "1234.5"
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var temp = "2342355".split(''); 
temp.splice(temp.length-2,0,'.');
var result = temp.join('');
```

Comment: This actually makes more sence

Comment: Thanks @Murplyx pls do not hesitate to mark it as your answer if it helped you.

Comment: You didn't generalize your solution to work for any position of the decimal, only just the "2" position indicated by the example. Otherwise, works well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var addDec = function(x, n){
  return x.truncate(x.length - n,".") + x.slice(-n);
}
```

Comment: I don't really know how the running time compares to the other solutions. I think it's roughly equivalent to using substr, but the syntax is a little more concise. Truncate is basically the inverse of slice - slice keeps everything to the right of the index, and truncate keeps everything to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged with regex, you can use replace

```
Regex:   (?=\d{2}$)
Replace with:  "."

result = subject.replace(/(?=\d{2}$), ".");
```

but there are probable "faster" ways to do this.